# Filter a lookup based on selection of the other in ms-access

Tags: database, ms-access, lookup

I have two look up tables in an access database. I want the results of the Colleges Look-up to filer out the results of the Departments look-up. I have used [Forms]![Form]![College] to do this. It works the 1st time but when I choose a different option for colleges the departments list remains filtered on the previous choice. It does not update.

How do I solve the update problem?

Answer (score 0):

Get thee to UtterAccess for detailed help on this:
http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Cascading_Combo_Boxes